# What are the “spiritual sacrifices” in 1 Peter 2:5?

Tags: 1-peter

1 Peter 2:5 NASB

> you also, as living stones, are being built up as a spiritual house for a holy priesthood, to offer up spiritual sacrifices acceptable to God through Jesus Christ.

What are the “spiritual sacrifices” Peter is referring to?

Answer (score 3):

Prayer, Praise, Holiness and Fasting these are some of the spiritual sacrifices.

**Prayer**

> Let my prayer be set forth before thee as incense; and the lifting up
> of my hands as the evening sacrifice. **(Psalm 141:2 AKJV)**

**Praise**

> By him therefore let us offer the sacrifice of praise to God
> continually, that is, the fruit of our lips giving thanks to his name.
> **(Hebrews 13:15 AKJV)**

**Holiness**

> I beseech you therefore, brethren, by the mercies of God, that ye
> present your bodies a living sacrifice, holy, acceptable unto God,
> which is your reasonable service. 2 And be not conformed to this
> world: but be ye transformed by the renewing of your mind, that ye may
> prove what is that good, and acceptable, and perfect, will of
> God. **(Romans 12:1–2 AKJV)**

**Fasting**

> The sacrifices of God are a broken spirit: a broken and a contrite
> heart, O God, thou wilt not despise. **(Psalm 51:17 AKJV)**

Related to fasting Isaiah 58:3-7 the does and don't while fasting!

Comment: @ There is nothing like letting scripture interpret scripture! Especially on this important aspect of Christian life. Us theologians have nothing to add...just a lot of catching up to do with prayer and praise.

Answer (score 3):

Before answering, we should note that the community of Christians that compose the "Kingdom of God" is, according to Peter (Quoting Ex 19:5, 6):

> 1 Peter 2:9 - But you are a chosen people, **a royal priesthood**, a
> holy nation, a people for God’s own possession, to proclaim the
> virtues of Him who called you out of darkness into His marvelous
> light.

Thus, every Christian is a priest with Christ as our Great High Priest (Heb 13:15, 1 Peter 5:1-5), and, every priest must have something to offer (Heb 8:3).

The NT explicitly lists the spiritual sacrifices (1 Peter 2:5) that the Holy Nation of Priests must offer:

1. Heb 13:15 - Through Jesus, therefore, let us continually offer to God **a sacrifice of praise**, the fruit of lips that confess His name.
2. Heb 13:16 - And do not neglect **to do good and to share with others**, for with such sacrifices God is pleased.
3. Rom 12:1 - Therefore I urge you, brothers, on account of God’s mercy, to offer **your bodies as living sacrifices**, holy and pleasing to God, which is your spiritual service of worship.
4. Eph 5:2 - and **walk in love**, just as Christ also loved us and gave Himself up for us as an offering and a sacrifice to God, into an aroma of a sweet smell.
5. Phil 4:18 - I have all I need and more, now that **I have received your gifts** from Epaphroditus. They are a fragrant offering, **an acceptable sacrifice**, well-pleasing to God.